# Unable to start XAMPP on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, webserver, web-development, xampp

I downloaded `XAMPP` on Windows 7 and installed it in `E:`, but I am unable to start it.

When I check `http://localhost` in the browser, I see an error page.

[image: apache is running but can't see localhost working]

In the XAMPP control panel, Apache is running:

[image: you can see control panel apache is running]

Comment: @slhck you can check I added images now

Comment: Hmm, actually it should [show a green "started"](http://www.apachefriends.org/images/5600.jpg) next to the Apache service. When you check your Windows processes, is there anything related to `httpd` or `Apache`?

Comment: Can you right-click on `Computer` in your `Start-menu` and click on `properties`? Is `32-bit` or `64-bit Operating system` listed under `System type:`?

Comment: It is a 64 bit OS and when I check process there is nothing related to httpd or apache

Comment: Try checking for more details in the Apache log file. Should be under E:\xamp\xampp\apache\logs\error_log (from the top of my head, might slightly differ), that should give more details on what's going wrong.

Comment: Maybe there is a program that is already using port 80 (Skype for example) You can use [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) to look for the that is using it. Port 80 is required to start apache (but you can use another port).

Comment: are you using skype? or another program that use internet? probably apache start fails...